# How to remove color from clothes

Tags: cleaning, clothing

When I soaked my new clothes in detergent, I was not aware that some previously washed clothes had left some colors in the water. Those colors have stained my brand new clothes, and I have tried to remove it by applying tooth paste and other things but the colors won't go away.

Please suggest some ways to remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Wash it again, in the hottest water it can stand (read label) using your normal detergent and a Color Catcher(tm). This works for me about 90% of the time *if* I haven't used the dryer to dry it. If a dryer was used, try it anyway, you might get lucky. It also might take more than 1 washing depending how intense the color transfer, type of material, time passed, etc. Good Luck!